# Silverlight 5 validation issue

Tags: validation, textbox, silverlight-5.0

i'm trying to validate the data entry of my project using the validation in silverlight

this is the result

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/842/immagineleb.png/

as you can see the borders of almost all the textboxes are red, actually, in this case, no one of them should be red! And in all of the tooltips there's the same message.

there are the properties of the object that i use in the data context of the form

```
    private int matricola;
    public int Matricola
    {
        get { return matricola; }
        set 
        {
            ValidateRequiredInt("Matricola", value, "Inserire un numero");
            matricola = value;
            OnNotifyPropertyChanged("Matricola");
        }
    }

    private String cognome;
    public String Cognome
    {
        get { return cognome; }
        set 
        {
            ValidateRequiredString("Cognome", value, "Inserire cognome");
            cognome = value;
            OnNotifyPropertyChanged("Cognome");
        }
    }

    private String nome;
    public String Nome
    {
        get { return nome; }
        set 
        {
            ValidateRequiredString("Nome", value, "Inserire nome");
            nome = value;
            OnNotifyPropertyChanged("Nome");
        }
    }

    private String codiceUtente;
    public String CodiceUtente
    {
        get { return codiceUtente; }
        set 
        {
            ValidateRequiredString("CodiceUtente", value, "Inserire codice utente");
            codiceUtente = value;
            OnNotifyPropertyChanged("CodiceUtente");
        }
    }

    private String password;
    public String Password
    {
        get { return password; }
        set 
        {
            ValidateRequiredString("Password", value, "Inserire password");
            password = value;
            OnNotifyPropertyChanged("Password");
        }
    }

    private int? idOrario;
    public int? IdOrario
    {
        get { return idOrario; }
        set { idOrario = value; }
    }

    private DateTime? dataAssunzione;
    public DateTime? DataAssunzione
    {
        get { return dataAssunzione; }
        set 
        {
            if (value != null)
            {
                ValidateDateTime("DataAssunzione", (DateTime)value, "Immettere una data corretta");
                if (((DateTime)value).Year == 1 && ((DateTime)value).Month == 1 && ((DateTime)value).Day == 1)
                {
                    dataAssunzione = null;
                }
                else
                {
                    dataAssunzione = value;
                }
                OnNotifyPropertyChanged("DataAssunzione");
            }
            else
            {
                dataAssunzione = null;
            }
        }
    }

    private DateTime? dataLicenziamento;
    public DateTime? DataLicenziamento
    {
        get { return dataLicenziamento; }
        set 
        {
            if (value != null)
            {
                ValidateDateTime("DataLicenziamento", (DateTime)value, "Immettere una data corretta");
                if (((DateTime)value).Year == 1 && ((DateTime)value).Month == 1 && ((DateTime)value).Day == 1)
                {
                    dataLicenziamento = null;
                }
                else
                {
                    dataLicenziamento = value;
                }
                OnNotifyPropertyChanged("DataLicenziamento");
            }
            else
            {
                dataLicenziamento = null;
            }
        }
    }

    private int idGruppoAnag;
    public int IdGruppoAnag
    {
        get { return idGruppoAnag; }
        set { idGruppoAnag = value; }
    }

    private int? costoOrario;
    public int? CostoOrario
    {
        get { return costoOrario; }
        set 
        {
            if (value != null)
            {
                ValidateInt("CostoOrario", (int)value, "Immettere un numero o lasciare il campo vuoto");
                if (value == 0 || value == -1)
                {
                    costoOrario = null;
                }
                else
                {
                    costoOrario = value;
                }
                OnNotifyPropertyChanged("CostoOrario");
            }
            else
            {
                costoOrario = null;
            }
        }
    }
```

and these are the methods used for the validation

```
    protected bool ValidateRequiredInt(string propName, int value, string errorText)
    {
        if (DataErrors.ContainsKey(propName))
        {
            DataErrors[propName].Remove(errorText);
        }

        if (value == 0 || value == -1)
        {
            AddError(propName, errorText);
            return false;
        }
        OnErrorsChanged(propName);
        return true;
    }

    //validazione dei campi che richiedono numeri interi nullable
    protected bool ValidateInt(string propName, int value, string errorText)
    {
        if (DataErrors.ContainsKey(propName))
        {
            DataErrors[propName].Remove(errorText);
        }
        if (value == 0)
        {
            AddError(propName, errorText);
            return false;
        }
        OnErrorsChanged(propName);
        return true;
    }

    //validazione dei campi che richiedono stringhe
    protected bool ValidateRequiredString(string propName, string value, string errorText)
    {
        //Clear any existing errors since we're revalidating now
        if (DataErrors.ContainsKey(propName))
        {
            DataErrors[propName].Remove(errorText);
        }
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
        {
            AddError(propName, errorText);
            return false;
        }
        OnErrorsChanged(propName);
        return true;
    }

    protected bool ValidateDateTime(string propName, DateTime value, string errorText)
    {
        //Clear any existing errors since we're revalidating now
        if (DataErrors.ContainsKey(propName))
        {
            DataErrors[propName].Remove(errorText);
        }
        if (value.Year == 9999 && value.Month == 12 && value.Day == 31)
        {
            AddError(propName, errorText);
            return false;
        }
        OnErrorsChanged(propName);
        return true;
    }
```

i'm also using using a dataconverter, in the two "Data" textboxes, and numberconverter, in the matricola and costo textboxes, as locals resources and i can say that they work fine.

i'm missing something?

Answer (score 0):

How about implementing INotifyDataErrorInfo?

In a view-model base class:

```
    public abstract class BaseViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged, INotifyDataErrorInfo
{
    #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

#endregion

    #region INotifyDataErrorInfo Members

    public event EventHandler<DataErrorsChangedEventArgs> ErrorsChanged;

    public System.Collections.IEnumerable GetErrors(string propertyName)
    {   
    ....
    }

    public System.Collections.IEnumerable GetErrors()
    {
    ...
    }

//Plus methods to push errors into an underlying error dictionary used by the above error get methods
}
```

Expand on this and you will have reusable base class for all view-models.
Validate properties in the appropriate setters. If they fail validation then push an error into the error dictionary keyed by property name. If validation succeeds then remove the validation error (if any) from the the dictionary for the property.

You will need to fire the ErrorsChanged event when you change the dictionary, but this can be achieved by having a protected

```
SetErrorForProperty(string propName, object error)
```

method whcih wraps this up.
Clearing an error can be done by passing null to this method and/or by having a separate

> ClearErrorsFroProperty(string propName)

method.